# MVVM update combobox itemsSource and refresh

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm working on a WPF project and its MVVM. I got a problem about refreshing combobox binding value. So, here its the case, i have a combobox and button on my grid. I need to change datasource then refresh to see new values according to selected one step before.

Please tell me what is the best method to like next button? After that maybe need to like previous button.

```
public MyScriptForm(IMyScriptModel viewModel) {
  this.Model=viewModel;
  InitializeComponent();
  Height=Double.NaN;
  Width=Double.NaN;
}
public IMyScriptModel Model {
  get {
    return this.DataContext as IMyScriptModel;
  }
  set {
    this.DataContext=value;
  }
}
private void btnNext_Click(object sender,
RoutedEventArgs e) {
  /// to what ?
  Model.cbxAnswer.Clear();
  Model.cbxAnswer.add("Step2Data");
}
Create{//its a huge project, this working on when this form created
  myScript.Model.cbxAnswer.Add("1");
  myScript.Model.cbxAnswer.Add("2");
  myScript.Model.cbxAnswer.Add("3");
  }
destroy{}

////////////////////////
//Onmy model 
public List<string> cbxAnswer {
  get {
    return m_cbxAnswer;
  }
  set {
    m_cbxAnswer=value;
    OnPropertyChanged("cbxAnswer");
  }
}
public List<string> m_cbxAnswer=new List<string>();
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
 protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
  if (PropertyChanged !=null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

XAML:

```
<Grid>
  <ComboBox Name="cbxAnswer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,130,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" Height="25" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=cbxAnswer}" />
  <Button Name="btnNext" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="215,130,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Content="İlerle" Click="btnNext_Click" />

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are just adding and removing from the collection (as opposed to creating a new one). This means that you need a collection that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

A very convenient class that already does this is `ObservableCollection<T>`, which I would use instead of `List<T>` here, and anywhere else you need collection changes to propagate to the UI.

If you are truly doing a *full* refresh, you may consider just recreating the collection instead of doing add/removes. This could give you a net performance gain, as doing each operation individually must be handled by the UI, as opposed to all at once.

Comment: hello again, my model implements interface like Imyscriptmodel, i defined my list on that interface then on my model(with imp.) like List<string> cbxAnswer { get; set; }. Is it the right way to defined observableCollection and bind to combobox's itemsSource ? for example //ObservableCollection<String> cbxAnswer {get; set;}//

Comment: @user3064819 Yes, that will fix additions/removals not propagating to the UI. To get *full* refreshes to work, you'll need to raise `PropertyChanged` as well.

Comment: God Bless You! ObservableCollection solve my entirely problem :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, I knew it old Q, but How can I recreate new one collection without breaking Binding which was created to old one collection?

Comment: Assuming you INPC the property that was bound; it should just work. Not sure what you are concerned about @dellos

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, Sorry I'm new in Xaml Binding system, I was thought that when Binding form XAML to ViewModel properties this Binding will be break when I do assign a new value to these properties in VM side. Now I note that Public properties have backup private filed so the Binding just works.

Comment: If you assign to the public property, and have INPC setup, nothing should break @dellos

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, Hi me again, what is INPC mean by the way.

Comment: @dellos INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: I have similar issue but in my case I am using Dictionary<string, object>. How can I change it to observableCollection? So my UI gets updated on removal or addition of a value in dictionary/observableCollection. I am new to WPF MVVM stuff. Please guide

Comment: Sounds like a good separate question (and make sure to google first!)